# Where can I get a list of all the 72 initial NXT stakeholder addresses to see distribution?

Tags: nxt

Where can I find a list of all the nxt accounts that were the initial 72 seeders? I want to find out to see how many of these accounts have moved their funds and dispersed it to the public.

Comment: It was issued from the account NXT-MRCC-2YLS-8M54-3CMAJ. However, the one NXT explorer I found won't allow you to look up transactions from it. Annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 73 initial stakeholder accounts are included in the [genesis block of the blockchain](http://blocks.nxtcrypto.org/nxt/nxt.cgi?action=1000&blk=2680262203532249785).

You could write a script to extract the detailed information you are looking for from the block chain, using the [NXT API](https://wiki.nxtcrypto.org/wiki/Nxt_API). However, even if you follow the money trail, there is no way to know who owns the destination accounts -- some may be owned by the original stakeholders.

Perhaps a more useful study is to analyze the blockchain to determine the amount of NXT concentrated in large accounts vs. small accounts. This has been done in a graph [here](http://charts.nxtcrypto.org/cDistribution.aspx). Notice that much distribution took place during the first month or two and continues at a slower pace since then. You can click along the horizontal axis to remove selected bands in the graph.

Comment: is there one where it also lists how much each of those accounts have remaining?

Comment: I elaborated on this in the answer above.